# Can i use HTTP/2 between origin and cloudflare servers?(Apache)

Tags: apache, cloudflare, http2

I try to do, but when i turn to bypass my domain A record, the protocol h2 is working.
All correct in browser and apache logs.

When i turn on the cloudflare on the domain, the browser is working fine(I know the CF is working on HTTP2 protocol with the clients).

But I saw these in the apache logs:
“GET / HTTP/1.1” 302 5067
"GET /en/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5068
"POST /en/ajax/user HTTP/1.1" 200 77

It's using http/1.1, but I don't know why.

I try to force http2 protocol, but no difference.

Any idea ?:slightly_smiling_face:

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTTP/2 to origin as of June 14th, 2022:

```
1.  Log into the [Cloudflare dashboard](https://dash.cloudflare.com/login) and select your account.
2.  Choose the domain that will use HTTP/2 to Origin.
3.  Click **Network**.
4.  Under **HTTP/2 to Origin** set the toggle to On.
```

**Refs are:**

- https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflare-docs/blob/production/content/cache/concepts/enable-http2-to-origin.md <s>`https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflare-docs/blob/production/content/cache/how-to/enable-http2-to-origin.md`</s>
- `https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/how-to/enable-http2-to-origin/`

Answer (score 4):

Cloudflare plans to use HTTP 1.1 to the origin for the foreseeable future.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/214534978-Are-the-HTTP-2-or-SPDY-protocols-supported-between-Cloudflare-and-the-origin-server-